# Ridiculously low current gain in 2N3904-based current mirror

Tags: transistors, current-source

I am learning about current mirrors and decided to build one out of discrete transistors.
The mirror is built out of two 2N3904 transistors, selected for their theoretically high current gain at 20mA @ VCE = 1V.
[image]

After building the circuit on stripboard and testing its performance I noticed a giant base current of nearly 2mA and after some calculations I determined the current gain to be just shy of 9. I was expecting a base current somewhere in between 100 uA and 200 uA and a current gain between 150 and 200.

I don't understand why this happened.

The measured values and the circuit schematic.

[image]

**Why is this happening and is there a way I could solve the issue of the minuscule current gain?**

Comment: Did you match the transistors?

Comment: @SredniVashtar I did not match the transistors. Would it have such a big impact on the functioning of the circuit?

Comment: For the BJT on the left side, collector current IC= 20.21m - 1.9mA = 18.31mA. IE is also 18.31mA according to your measurements. So, IB is very small. Does that mean all that 1.9mA is going into base of the right side BJT? Please disconnect the right side BJT and check what happens to the 1.9mA first

Comment: @sai I made a typo that 1.9 mA should have been 3.8mA. So IC is 20.21m - 3.8m = 16.41 mA.

Comment: If the transistors have slightly different Vbe vs Ib characteristics, due to the exponential dependence of Ib from Vbe I would expect considerable differences in the two base currents for the same Vbe. I wouldn't rule out a thermal runaway that will make one transistor hog all the current.

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs, I hope you have not swapped the collector and emitter.

Comment: @sai I think I did that actually. I think I searched for the wrong pinout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the collector and emitter have been swapped (as confirmed by you in the comments), that could explain the low current gain.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did reverse the pins of the transistor and the emitter current and the reference current were practically the same.

Answer (score 6):

If you swap emitter and collector, the reverse beta is typically about right to yield these results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the time you've taken to simulate the circuit, it certainly helped confirm the theory that I had accidentally reversed the pins of the transistors.

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs General purpose transistors typically have a reverse beta of around 10 so it makes sense. There are some rare transistors with almost symmetrical gain and breakdown voltages but they are .. rare. Fortunately the supply voltage was 5V so the transistors were not at risk of damage- except for some RF transistors most can easily handle 5V Veb.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany "There are some rare transistors with almost symmetrical gain..." What a journey down memory lane! :-) IIRC, I encountered them in my dabbling with CRT TVs in the 80s, such kind of BJTs were employed somewhere in the HV stages. I can't recall if they were in the beam deflection circuits or maybe in the CRT (electron beam electrodes) driver. Are they still used today for something?

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine They used to be used in analog switches, though today MOSFETs are pretty much better in every way. Some are still used for analog mute switches, eg. 2SC3326. Sometimes the symbol was drawn with two emitters (one with arrow pointing away in place of the collector, not two on the same side of the base TTL-style).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Nice to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should make RE1 and RE2 = ~ 0.

Here is what I get :

[image]

Ib = ~ 51 uA and Ic = ~ 4.4 mA ...

And at 20 mA ...

[image]

Comment: Emitter resistors are a standard way to improve matching of mirrors based on discrete BJTs. They don't explain the high base current, and their omission is unlikely to improve anything.

Comment: Just to explain what the OP should get ...